# Show popup box in if conditions in php

Tags: php, modal-dialog

I am trying to show a popup box in if conditions.
Here is my HTML :

```
<div id="my-confirm-dialog" class="dialog-overlay">
        <div class="dialog-card">
          <div class="dialog-question-sign"><i class="fa fa-question"></i></div>
          <div class="dialog-info">
            <h5>Thank You !</h5>
            <p>Your Messag has been sent.</p>
            <button class="dialog-confirm-button">OK</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Here is my Script :

```
<script>

        $(document).ready(function() {
          function showDialog(id){
            var dialog = $('#' + id),
            card = dialog.find('.dialog-card');
            dialog.fadeIn();
            card.css({
              'margin-top' : -card.outerHeight()/2
            });
          }

          function hideAllDialogs(){
            $('.dialog-overlay').fadeOut();
            }

            $('.dialog-confirm-button, .dialog-reject-button').on('click', function () {
              hideAllDialogs();
            });

            $('.dialog-overlay').on('click', function (e) {
              if(e.target == this){
                hideAllDialogs();
              }
            });

            $(document).keyup(function(e) {
              if (e.keyCode == 27) {
                hideAllDialogs();
              }
            });

            $('.dialog-show-button').on('click', function () {
              var toShow = $(this).data('show-dialog');
              showDialog(toShow);
            });
          });

    </script>
```

Here is my button :

```
<span class="dialog-show-button" data-show-dialog="my-confirm-dialog">Dialog Button</span>
```

Whenever, I click on the button, a popup box is arrived. till now everyythin is fine. Now what i am trying to do is, when I sent mail and the condition is true, This popup box will appear.
Here is the condition and in this alert box is working perfectly.

```
if ($mail == true){
echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("Thankyou for Contacting Shagun Sweets")</script>';
}
```

I just want to show the popup box in the place of alert box, I have already tried something like this but not helpful.

```
<?php
if ($mail == true){
    echo "<script>";
    echo "showDialog('my-confirm-dialog');";
    echo "</script>";
}
?>
```

Please help me out.

Comment: You currently have your `showDialog` function wrapped into a document ready handler - so it likely does not even exist, when your script block that you output tries to call it directly, without any “delay”. Either move the function out of the ready handler - or wrap the call into one, too. (If the calling section comes after the other one.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define the `showDialog` function outside the DOM ready function.

And, do this instead:

```
$script = '<script type="text/javascript">';
$script .= 'showDialog('my-confirm-dialog');';
$script .= '</script>';

echo $script;
```

If your alert is working, this should then also work

Comment: Showing this error :  

contact.php:206 Uncaught ReferenceError: showDialog is not defined

Answer (score 0):

Your php script should have worked. But it is possible that it isn't working because you are actually checking if mail is true before the page loads. here is what I suggest you do, edit your php function to:

```
<?php if($mail == true){
    echo "<script>var show_dialog = true;</script>";
} ?>
```

in your script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // put me in the end
    if(show_dialog != undefined && show_dialog){
       showDialog('my-confirm-dialog');
    }
});
```

Comment: Not working, i have kept your script in last f body but still not working

Comment: Make sure to put the <?php if($mail == true) 

part in the TOP of the html.

the javascript one should be under your function showDialog and inside the document ready

Comment: An other thing to possibly try is this:

<?php if($mail == true){
   echo "showDialog('my-confirm-dialog');";
} ?>

Put the above one inside your document ready , under the showDialog function! it is not very friendly, but it works.